# Strange behaviour of array_keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've got a short question that I've been wondering about for a while. There is a perfect workaround, but I'd like to know what the problem really is.

I've got an array ($lines) consisting of underlying associative arrays. I want to get the indexes of one (basically any random one) of those underlying arrays, so I use:

```
$headers = array_keys($lines[0]);
```

However, this gives me back the following error:

> Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

But then, when I use this instead:

```
$line0 = $lines[0];
$headers = array_keys($line0);
```

Everything works exactly as I want it to. Now as far as I can see, these two should be perfectly equivalent, so I was wondering if this is a bug in PHP, or if I just fail to understand something here.

PHP version is 5.3.1

The $lines array looks like this in my test case:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 00
            [name] => John Doe
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 007
            [name] => James Bond
        )
)
```

Comment: Can you print out what $lines is?

Comment: Which PHP version as well. Is this reproducible?

Comment: I've added it to the question. Sorry for giving incomplete information.

Comment: You should post a code snippet that reproduces the issue, even if you're 100% sure that `array_keys()` is buggy. If a builtin funcion that's been around for years did not work in *any* circumstance someone would had noticed before ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce. 
I wrote the following file:

```
<?php

$lines = array(
    array("A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3),
    array("A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3),
    array("A" => 1, "B" => 2, "C" => 3)
);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(array_keys($lines[0]));
echo "</pre>";
```

And it outputs correctly:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
}
```

So I guess it's either a bug in your program or in your php version but nothing "normal".

Comment: what if you write `<?php  $a = array( 0 => array( 'a' => 'test') ); array_keys($a[0]);` ?

Comment: It gives me back
`Array
(
    [0] => a
)`
Which is exactly what I would expect. Then why doesn't mine work? Making a sad, sad face here.

Comment: Unfortunately and obviously, with the example you given, it cannot be reproduced by anyone, so as said, try to post a reproducible example (with more code, closer to your real one).
It may be a PHP bug, but it's more likely a bug in your program, maybe hard to see. Maybe in your real code $lines is passed by reference and simultaneously modified somewhere else or ?.. 
Also, not sure if you can actually do that, but a debugger with a stop point here could help to inspect the mess.

Comment: I was copying the exact code snippet from my program, as suddenly everything magically worked. I'm even more flabbergasted right now, but the problem seems to be gone, so I'll just attribute this to the general surreal nature of my life. Thanks for guiding me to the answer, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Try and write out the issue in as few lines as possible to see if you can recreate, if so then you need to submit to http://bugs.php.net